# how do I merge two json with practically the same elements

Tags: python, json

I have a problem that I can't merge two jonsons that are basically related. I tried as follows

```
path = os.path.join('../resources/data.json')
    if not os.path.exists(path) or os.stat(path).st_size == 0:
      with open(path, 'w') as f:
        json.dump({}, f)
    print(" ")
    with open(path, 'r+') as f:
      obj = json.load(f)
    print(direc)
    print(obj)
    jso = '{"2015":{"08":{"26":{"23365116":{"23365116_HORARIA_2015-08-26_23-01.dat":{"dowloaded":"false","moved":"false"}}}}}}'
    my_dict = json.loads(jso)
    d = obj.copy()
    d.update(my_dict)
    print(d)
```

wanted something like this in the end

```
{"2015":{"08":{"26":{"23365116":{"23365116_HORARIA_2015-08-26_23-01.dat":{"dowloaded":"false","moved":"false","23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat":{"dowloaded":"false","moved":"false"}}}}}}
```

The json found in the data.json file is as follows

```
{"2015":{"08":{"26":{"23365116":{"23365116_15MIN_2015-08-26_23-01.dat":{"dowloaded":"false","moved":"false"}}}}}}
```

Comment: Please provide desired input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dictionary unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) to combine two dictionaries

Once you load the 2 json files to dictionaries you can do something like this:

```
one = {"1": 1}
two = {"2": 2}
{**one, **two}
{'1': 1, '2': 2}
```